# What is the structure of virtual tables in C++?

Tags: c++, vtable

For Example I have two "intefaces" and class type:

```
class IPlugin
{
  public:
    virtual void Load(void) = 0;
    virtual void Free(void) = 0;
};

class IFoo
{
  public:
    virtual void Foo(void) = 0;
};


class Tester: public IPlugin, public IFoo
{
   public:
           Tester() {};
          ~Tester() {};

           virtual void Load()
           {
              // Some code here
           }

           virtual void Free()
           {
              // Some code here
           }

           virtual void Foo(void)
           {
              // Some code here
           }
 };
```

What structure vtab actually has for instance of type `Tester`? And how would be  `dynamic_cast` operator act ( I mean how `dynamic_cast` operator would scan vtab for valid reference type convertion) in expression:

```
Tester* t = new Tester();
IPlugin* plg = dynamic_cast<IPlugin*>(t);
IFoo* f = dynamic_cast<IFoo*>(plg);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look here http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/

Comment: The implementation of virtual function calls is not defined in the C++ standard. You won't get an answer that is correct for all compilers and compiler versions.

Comment: @DumbCoder: thank you for link, but as it turned out there is no common answer for my question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Virtual tables in C++ is an implementation detail. One possible implementation is shown on the diagram below.

[image: Virtual table diagram]

Two instances of the class (A and B) exists. Each instance has two vtbl pointers and the vtbl contains pointers to actual code.

In your example there is no instance data, but I have for illustrative purposes assumed that each class contains some instance data.

When a pointer to `Tester` is cast to a pointer to `IFoo` the pointer is adjusted as shown on the diagram. Instead of pointing to the start of the instance data it points to the `IFoo` part of the instance data.

The neat thing is that a caller using an `IFoo` pointer doesn't have any knowledge about the data surrounding the `IFoo` part of the class. The same can be said of for a caller using an `IPlugin` pointer. This pointer happens to point to the start of the instance data also pointed to by a `Tester` pointer but only a caller using a `Tester` pointer knows the entire layout of the instance data.

Using `dynamic_cast` requires RTTI (Run-Time Type Information) which is not on the diagram. The vtbl will contain additional type information that given a say `IFoo` pointer to an instance of `Tester` allows the code at run-time to discover the actual type of object pointed by the pointer and use that to downcast the pointer.

Answer (score 6):

> What structure vtab actually has for instance of type Tester?

The mechanism of virtual dispatching is implementation-defined. vtable and vptr are not required by the C++ Standard and that knowledge isn't even necessary for programmers to program in C++, because you cannot access the virtual table (even if your compiler implements this); its generated by the compiler and added to your code, like it does lots of things to your code before it converts it into machine code.

---

```
Tester* t = new Tester();
IPlugin* plg = dynamic_cast<IPlugin*>(t);
IFoo* f = dynamic_cast<IFoo*>(plg);
```

Here `dynamic_cast` is not needed in the second line. The following is enough:

```
Tester* t = new Tester();
IPlugin* plg = t;                 //upcast          - dynamic_cast not needed
IFoo* f=dynamic_cast<IFoo*>(plg); //horizontal-cast - dynamic_cast needed
```

`dynamic_cast` is not needed in upcast; its needed in downcast and horizontal-cast only.

```
Tester* tester1 = dynamic_cast<Tester*>(plg); //downcast - dynamic_cast needed
Tester* tester2 = dynamic_cast<Tester*>(f);   //downcast - dynamic_cast needed
```

Comment: @Nawaz: Remember the virtual mechanism implementation detail Q a year ago? :)

Comment: @Als: Where? Which topic? I don't remember :-s

Comment: @Nawaz: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352032/a-question-about-virtual-mechanism-in-c) Check the OP & the first commentor :)

Comment: @Als: Haha.. yeah, you remember that :P... So what was your point? Are you trying to make any point here?

Comment: @Nawaz: Naah, No point to make..just struck my mind remembering the good old days :P

Comment: If you are doing windows programming the VTable binary format is defined (supposing you wish to do COM work, .NET is likely similar?). That is, while C++ doesn't define what happens, certain OS's certainly do define the exactly structure of the VTable.

Answer (score 6):

In *ISO/IEC 14882 Second edition 2003-10-15* there is not exist such terms like
vptr, virtual table, so it is completely up to compiler implementators.

Info about impl. in microsoft's visual C++:
http://www.openrce.org/articles/files/jangrayhood.pdf

Article about impl. virtual tables in g++:
https://web.archive.org/web/20090123142656/http://phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html

Answer (score 3):

Virtual Mechanism(Virtual Pointer & Virtual Table) is not defined by the C++ standard. It is left out for the compiler to implement the mechanism in its own choosen way. It is an implementation detail of the compiler. Given that, the details of how the compiler will implement the virtual mechanism is abstracted from the user. What should matter is only the beahviors that are expected out of the virtual mechanism.

In your case:

```
Tester* t = new Tester(); 
IPlugin* plg = dynamic_cast<IPlugin*>(t); 
IFoo* f = dynamic_cast<IFoo*>(plg);
```

`plg` & `f` both will point to a valid object of their respective types because `t` is derives from both of them.

Ofcourse this does not answer the specific question you asked but just wanted to clear the detail on virtual mechanism being a implementation detail of the compilers.

Comment: Thank you! I really thought that vtab specified in standard :)