# virtual table and _vptr storage scheme

Tags: c++, vtable, vptr, virtual-table

Can someone explains how this virtual table for the different class is stored in memory? When we call a function using pointer how do they make a call to function using address location? Can we get these virtual table memory allocation size using a class pointer? I want to see how many memory blocks is used by a virtual table for a class. How can I see it?

```
class Base
{
public:
    FunctionPointer *__vptr;
    virtual void function1() {};
    virtual void function2() {};
};

class D1: public Base
{
public:
    virtual void function1() {};
};

class D2: public Base
{
public:
    virtual void function2() {};
};
int main()
{
    D1 d1;
    Base *dPtr = &d1;
    dPtr->function1();
}
```

Thanks! in advance

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

Comment: The vtable is implementation-dependent, there's no standard way to access it.

Comment: So, @Barmar is there any way we can access vtable or see how much memory vtable used?

Comment: Not in any portable way.

Comment: Are you actually interested in examining the vtable from within the program? For example, are you trying to somehow change it at run-time? Or are you just trying to figure out how much space is being taken up by the vtable, for example, to evaluate the costs of using virtual functions in your program?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first point to keep in mind is a disclaimer: none of this is actually guaranteed by the standard. The standard says what the code needs to look like and how it should work, but doesn't actually specify exactly how the compiler needs to make that happen.

That said, essentially all C++ compilers work quite similarly in this respect.

So, let's start with non-virtual functions. They come in two classes: static and non-static.

The simpler of the two are static member functions. A static member function is almost like a global function that's a `friend` of the class, except that it also needs the class`s name as a prefix to the function name.

Non-static member functions are a little more complex. They're still normal functions that are called directly--but they're passed a hidden pointer to the instance of the object on which they were called. Inside the function, you can use the keyword `this` to refer to that instance data. So, when you call something like `a.func(b);`, the code that's generated is pretty similar to code you'd get for `func(a, b);`

Now let's consider virtual functions. Here's where we get into vtables and vtable pointers. We have enough indirection going on that it's probably best to draw some diagrams to see how it's all laid out. Here's pretty much the simplest case: one instance of one class with two virtual functions:

[image]

So, the object contains its data and a pointer to the vtable. The vtable contains a pointer to each virtual function defined by that class. It may not be immediately apparent, however, why we need so much indirection. To understand that, let's look at the next (ever so slightly) more complex case: two instances of that class:

[image]

Note how each instance of the class has its own data, but they both share the same vtable and the same code--and if we had more instances, they'd still all share the one vtable among all the instances of the same class.

Now, let's consider derivation/inheritance. As an example, let's rename our existing class to "Base", and add a derived class. Since I'm feeling imaginative, I'll name it "Derived". As above, the base class defines two virtual functions. The derived class overrides one (but not the other) of those:

[image]

Of course, we can combine the two, having multiple instances of each of the base and/or derived class:

[image]

Now let's delve into that in a little more detail. The interesting thing about derivation is that we can pass a pointer/reference to an object of the derived class to a function written to receive a pointer/reference to the base class, and it still works--but if you invoke a virtual function, you get the version for the actual class, not the base class. So, how does that work? How can we treat an instance of the derived class as if it were an instance of the base class, and still have it work? To do it, each derived object has a "base class subobject". For example, lets consider code like this:

```
struct simple_base { 
    int a;
};

struct simple_derived : public simple_base {
    int b;
};
```

In this case, when you create an instance of `simple_derived`, you get an object containing two `int`s: `a` and `b`. The `a` (base class part) is at the beginning of the object in memory, and the `b` (derived class part) follows that. So, if you pass the address of the object to a function expecting an instance of the base class, it uses on the part(s) that exist in the base class, which the compiler places at the same offsets in the object as they'd be in an object of the base class, so the function can manipulate them without even knowing that it's dealing with an object of the derived class. Likewise, if you invoke a virtual function all it needs to know is the location of the vtable pointer. As far as it cares, something like `Base::func1` basically just means it follows the vtable pointer, then uses a pointer to a function at some specified offset from there (e.g., the fourth function pointer).

At least for now, I'm going to ignore multiple inheritance. It adds quite a bit of complexity to the picture (especially when virtual inheritance gets involved) and you haven't mentioned it at all, so I doubt you really care.

As to accessing any of this, or using in any way other than simply calling virtual functions: you may be able to come up with something for a specific compiler--but don't expect it to be portable at all. Although things like debuggers often need to look at such stuff, the code involved tends to be quite fragile and compiler-specific.

Comment: I think your pictures with `Derived::vtable` are misleading, because it looks like you'd need to look in `Base::vtable` for `func2`, but (as your text describes) `func1` and `func2` must be stored inline in `Derived::vtable`.  Also the picture could indicate that `func1`/`func2` in `Derived::vtable` could still point to `A::*` (if `Derived` didn't overwrite it).

Comment: If `vptr` of all the objects are referring to the same object then why wasn't `vptr` made one for the entire class?

Answer (score 4):

The virtual table is supposed to be shared between instances of a class. More precisely, it lives at the "class" level, rather than the instance level. Each instance has the overhead of actually having a pointer to the virtual table, if in it's hierarchy there are virtual functions and classes.

The table itself is at least the size necessary to hold a pointer for each virtual function. Other than that, it is an implementation detail how it's actually defined. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868431/what-is-the-structure-of-virtual-tables-in-c) for a SO question with more details about this.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the following answer contain almost everything you want to know regarding virtual tables:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16097013/8908931

If you are looking for something a little more specific (with the regular disclaimer that this might change between platforms, compilers, and CPU architectures):

1. When needed, a virtual table is being created for a class. The class will have only one instance of the virtual table, and each object of the class will have a pointer which will point to the memory location of this virtual table. The virtual table itself can be thought of as a simple array of pointers.
2. When you assigned the derived pointer to the base pointer, it also contain the pointer to the virtual table. This mean that the base pointer points to the virtual table of the derived class. The compiler will direct this call to an offset into the virtual table, which will contain the actual address of the function from the derived class.
3. Not really. Usually at the start of an object, there is a pointer to the virtual table itself. But this will not help you too much, as it is just an array of pointers, with no real indication of its size.
4. Making a very long answer short: For an exact size you can find this information in the executable (or in segments loaded from it to the memory). With enough knowledge of how the virtual table works, you can get a pretty accurate estimation, given you know the code, the compiler, and the target architecture.
   For the exact size, you can find this information in either the executable, or in segments in the memory which are being loaded from the executable. An executable is usually an ELF file, this kind of files, contain information which is needed to run a program. A part of this information is symbols for various kinds of language constructs such as variables, functions and virtual tables. For each symbol, it contains the size it takes in memory. So button line, you will need the symbol name of the virtual table, and enough knowledge in ELF in order to extract what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that Jerry Coffin gave is excellent in explaining how virtual function pointers work to achieve runtime polymorphism in C++.  However, I believe that it is lacking in answering where in memory the vtable is stored.  As others have pointed out this is not dictated by the standard.

However, there is an excellent [blog post(s)](https://www.martinkysel.com/demystifying-virtual-tables-in-c-part-3-virtual-tables/) by Martin Kysel that goes into great detail about where virtual tables are stored.  To summarize the blog post(s):

1. One vtable is created for every class (not instance) with virtual functions.  Each instance of this class points to the same vtable in memory
2. Each vtable is stored in read only memory of the resulting binary file
3. The disassembly for each function in the vtable is stored in the text section of the resulting ELF binary
4. Attempting to write over the vtable, located in read only memory, results in a Segmentation fault (as expected)

Answer (score -1):

Each class has a pointer to a list of functions, they are each in the same order for derived classes, then the specific functions that are overrided change at that position in the list.

When you point with a base pointer type, the pointed to object still has the correct _vptr.

Base's

```
 Base::function1()
 Base::function2()
```

D1's

```
 D1::function1()
 Base::function2()
```

D2's

```
 Base::function1()
 D2::function2()
```

Further derived drom D1 or D2 will just add their new virtual functions in the list below the 2 current.

When calling a virtual function we just call the corresponding index, function1 will be index 0

So your call

```
 dPtr->function1();
```

is actually

```
 dPtr->_vptr[0]();
```

Comment: Can you point to the section of the Standard that specifies this?