# What's this extra parameter passed into virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, virtual-destructor

I have this code:

```
class Class {
public:
    virtual ~Class() {}
};

int main()
{
    Class* object = new Class();
    delete object;
}
```

which I compile with Visual C++ 10 and get this disassembly for `delete object` statement:

```
delete object;
test        eax,eax  
je          wmain+23h (401041h)  
mov         edx,dword ptr [eax]  
push        1  
mov         ecx,eax  
call        dword ptr [edx]
```

and this for the actual destructor:

```
Class::`scalar deleting destructor':
test        byte ptr [esp+4],1  
push        esi  
mov         esi,ecx  
mov         dword ptr [esi],offset Class::`vftable' (402100h)  
je          Class::`scalar deleting destructor'+18h (401018h)  
push        esi  
call        dword ptr [__imp_operator delete (4020A8h)]  
pop         ecx  
mov         eax,esi  
pop         esi  
ret         4
```

What is that `push 1` doing at the call site and why is the `test` at the destructor entry point checking for that value and conditionally bypass call to `operator delete()`?

Comment: I'd suggest you tag this as `c++-cli`

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: That's what I see in Visual Studio Disassembly window.

Comment: @Gorpik but it's not c++-cli, I don't think

Comment: Right, but is this a Debug project configuration or Release?

Comment: See [this answer that shows the meaning of such hidden destructor parameter][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750280/how-does-virtual-destructor-work-in-c/7750873#7750873

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: That's Release with /O2 optimization.

Comment: @Rup: You are absolutely right. I seriously misread the question.

Comment: `test eax,eax` is checking for a null pointer. Not sure why it's in release code.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod You're explicitly allowed to call `delete null;`, and there's a chance the `new` returned a null so it's probably not allowed to optimise it away.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: Visual C++ emits really stupid code on some occasions - that very code is to make "delete null pointer" a no-op.

Comment: @Rup: Exactly, except `new` never returns `null`, yet Visual C++ still checks that.

Comment: @Rup,@sharp - makes sense now.

Comment: Never mind whether new can return NULL or not (it can if used with std::nothrow), delete still *must* check for the case when someone calls i.e. delete NULL;

Comment: @Nemanja Trifunovic: The compiler has all the code so that it can see when `new` is used without `nothrow` and therefore can't return null and therefore `delete` is done on a non-null pointer. The check can be eliminated, just Visual C++ fails to do so.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The argument is used by the destructor to know if it should call delete at the end.

3 cases where you don't want to call it :

- The destructor is called by a derived class destructor
- The object is allocated on the stack, thus not created with new.
- The object is a field of another object, thus not created by new

EDIT: Add a third case

Answer (score 6):

Basically, the virtual destructor also implements calling operator delete. The parameter is there to decide whether or not call it.

See [this answer that shows the meaning of such hidden destructor parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750280/how-does-virtual-destructor-work-in-c/7750873#7750873).

Comment: Is this hidden parameter specific to VC++ ? I thought that gcc had chosen the road of generating multiple destructors instead (3 if I remember correctly).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: This should be part of the ABI, so gcc should do the same on Windows (if it wants to be compatible). I haven't tried it, though.

Comment: @jpacelek: ah right, it's in the ABI. Actually, gcc works without this on Windows too... as long as you don't try to mix gcc and VC++ libraries :)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Hmm, I thought they tried to be binary compatible (like icc), but it seems they don't.

Comment: well, they are compatible at the C level as far as I know :)

Answer (score 5):

I believe the extra parameter tells the compiler which destructor is the derived-most one, so that it only deallocates memory once, at the appropriate level of inheritance. I've seen something similar in gcc if I recall correctly.

Comment: GCC emits 3 destructors, for every class: a regular destructor, deallocating destructor, and a subclass destructor.  It looks like VS just emits one and calls it with a bool.

Comment: @deft_code: Thanks for that comment:  Explains something I've been wondering about for a while!