# How is polymorphism implemented at low level in a language like c++ ?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I read in a book that polymorphism is implemented in c++ by three levels of pointers(using vtable) but are there other methods of implementing it in c++ .

Comment: Actually @Mat I was searching for tags with polymorphism that is why i was not able to find the answer you have referred to here. Anywayz thanx .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual functions can also be implemented directly with function pointers like this.

```
struct A
{
    void (*foo)(A *thiz);
    void (*goo)(A *thiz, int x);
};
```

But obviously this is less efficient than the normal implementations. And actually C++ implementations may differ a little when dealing with multiply inheritance and virtual base classes.

Comment: @Mat refer the picked answer in [Alternative virtual mechanism implementations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352032/alternative-virtual-mechanism-implementations)?.

Comment: @Mat Allow me to start typing the answer before you post the comment. And allow me to believe someone knows vtable can understand my explanation. That's OK.